# Changing the colour of an EpiUltraGrid

Tags: c#, .net, erp, epicorerp

I am trying to change the cell colour of an EpiUltraGrid in Epicor.

The EpiUltraGrid is based on the Infragistics UltraGrid.

I have tried the following line of code:

```
grdPOSuggestions.Rows[i].Cells[13].Appearanace.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```

But I am presented with the following error:

```
'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell' does not contain a definition for 'Appearanace'
```

How do I change a cells colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the spelling of "Appearance"

Comment: Oops... Thanks. Must be a Friday mistake!